# Why don't Opera's keyboard shortcuts sometimes work in Google's Search Results?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, opera, google-search

I use Opera. I like the keyboard shortcuts that have been recently added to the Google Search Results page.

The Tab and Arrow keys allow me to navigate between the various search results but sometimes, in the latest version of Opera, they don't work.

I assume Google changes its user interface very frequently; Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Maybe someone can clarify which 'latest version' of Opera they are experiencing this in? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background: I had the exact opposite feeling about the Google shortcuts, since they interfere with Opera's native shortcuts, in this case something so basic as the <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrows to scroll the page! This led me to inactivate javascript on the google.com-domain in site preferences.

If you for some reason have inactivated javascript (perhaps running some script blocker), this could be it.

A pragmatic solution if your keyboard shortcuts does not seem to work is to simply use Opera's native link navigating keyboard shortcuts: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or my personal preference most often: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open in a new tab in the background).

Also, you don't give which version is the "latest" in your question, but maybe just try updating to the actual latest version. As I'm writing, this is Opera 11.62.